# Should I keep the serial number of my phone private?

Tags: samsung, security, privacy

I've just purchased a new, sealed Samsung Galaxy S24 online and the seller is now asking me for a picture of the "About phone" page. He says it's to "keep track of the item", but I'm wondering whether it could be used for any malicious purposes.

The information he's asking for includes the serial number and IMEI but this seems to be openly available on the product box, so he technically could have already gotten it before selling the phone to me. Should I send the information to him or turn down the request?

[This website](https://www.guidingtech.com/66540/serial-number-privacy/) suggests that it might be possibly used for warranty claims but I think it's unlikely. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Just don't give it. What do you care if he wants to track the item? What benefit do you get out of it? As far as you know, you can only lose. If he is a scammer though, he is not very skilled since he didn't give you any personal incentive.